# Trying to extract value in text string for a new column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Here is an example of the ask:

```
Column 1(data)           Column 2(what the goal is)
lskadjf/5/kdjlj          5
kldjfl/8/lkjd            8
oieurow/10/lksajl        10
sldkjfjl                 (blank)
kjsdflj/dsjjfl           (blank)
lkdjflk/lkj              (blank)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Text.BetweenDelimiters` function.

```
Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column 1], "/", "/")
```

The GUI works fine for this. Just put `/` in both boxes.

[image: Extract Text Between Delimiters]

---

If you want to check that there are exactly two slashes, try this:

```
if Text.Select([Column1], {"/"}) = "//"
then Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1], "/", "/")
else null
```

Comment: This does work, but I have revised the ask. The data can have deviaitons like outline in the new changes. Is there a way to only have the values between "/" "/" and have everything else populate as blank?

Comment: You can check if `Column1` has exactly two `/` using `Text.Select`. See my edit.